Given a channel transition matrix ($\bf{P}$) of DMC channel, does the capacity of $\mathbf{P}$ equal to that achieved with $\mathbf{P}^T$?
I'm a bit confused with this.
Since $I(X;Y) = I(Y;X)$, at first I thought it implies that Capacity($\mathbf{P}$) = Capacity($\mathbf{P}^T$), i.e., the capacity achieved with a transition matrix, equals to that achieved with its transpose matrix.
But later I realized that $\mathbf{P}^T$ does not describe the inverse channel from $Y$ to $X$. The inverse channel should be $p(x|y)$, instead of $p(y|x)$.
Could anyone please provide a more rigorous explanation for this? Thanks a lot!
Edited: Thanks lily for figuring out that $\mathbf{P}$ is not necessarily stochastic, in which case we just cannot calculate the capacity of such an illegal transition matrix.
But I'm still wondering for an explanation for the case that $\mathbf{P}$ is double stochastic.

Please use MathJax Formatting.

Thanks Jonathan, the formatting has been revised.

What exactly does Capacity($P^T$) mean?  The matrix $P^T$ isn't necessarily stochastic just because $P$ is.

Thanks lily. By Capacity($\mathbf{P}^T$) I mean the capacity calculated with the transpose of matrix $\mathbf{P}$. Yes, I agree with you that $\mathbf{P}^T$ is not necessarily stochastic -- in this case, Capacity($\mathbf{P}^T$) does not make sense. But what if $\mathbf{P}$ is a double stochastic transition matrix? Can we say Capacity($\mathbf{P}$) equals Capacity($\mathbf{P}^T$) for the latter case?
